# Adding cocos2d library Adding issues

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I am new developer in cocos2d game development field and I am facing the some strange issue when creating the Cocos2d Project and the all files which shows below hierarchical form.

[image]

how to adding the cocos2d library.a into project form

In below screen added library in another ready project download from the internet but in my case there is no any cocos2d library shows

[image]

so my problem is that **"How add cocos2d library"** into our project.

Your help is much much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Follow my Cocos2D + ARC project setup tutorial](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enable-arc-cocos2d-project-video-tutorial/) and you'll end up with a project that has:

- cocos2d set up as a static library
- ARC enabled

You should also try [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com). It's a lot easier to start a cocos2d project, not having to deal with libraries and all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you can check [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial). It is very good and contains instructions how to add cocos2d library

Comment: But here problem for not create the problem but after the create i can't able to show the cocos2d library

Comment: When you select a new project in Xcode it will automatically give the option of adding a Cocos2d project.

Comment: can please more elaborate you anser please :-)

Comment: Follow the instructions in that tutorial to install cocos2d first. After you install, create a new project in xcode where it will automatically show you options to create a cocos2d based project. You dont have to worry about the library. I would suggest please go through that tutorial for the installation and project creation.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Cocos2d here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download)

Then open terminal and execute this commands.

```
$ cd cocos2d-iphone
$ ./install-templates.sh -f
```

After this, you can find cocos2d template app in Xcode.(Xcode->New Project->Cocos2D